# Swift pattern cannot match value of type

Tags: swift

Please consider following code:

```
enum RetailDemandReturnOperation {
    case salesReturn(value: MSRetailSalesReturnRealm)
    case demand(value: MSRetailDemandRealm)
}
```

In my class I have:

```
private var data: RetailDemandReturnOperation!
```

I have enum, now I try to switch to it type and get values:

```
 switch data {
        case .salesReturn(let value):
            break

        case .demand(let value):
            break
        }
```

However, I get:

> Pattern cannot match values of type 'RetailDemandReturnOperation!'

Why?

Comment: @MartinR yes it solve my problem. But i did not realise that problem is in force unwrap before u provide that link.